# Java Runtime Environment not found error when I open an application

Tags: java

I have Windows 7 64bit OS Installed on my laptop... When I open an application an error occurs:

> "Java runtime environment not found"

in an error dialogue box.

I have tried to solve the issue by re-installing of JRE and Java. But error remain same.

Can somebody help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: There is no one to answer my Query..... :-(

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of applications which are developed in Java and they run on JRE x86 and couple of them need JRE x64. Don't think too much on this, simply install both versions of JRE i.e JRE x86 and x64. I am sure that will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should check your "Path" environment variable. Try opening a command prompt and checking to see if it's finding java.

```
java -version
```

You could also try running your software via a *.bat file to make sure it's looking in the right place, as follows:

```
@echo on
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
java -jar MySoftware.jar
PATH
@echo off
```